# using Hibernare Bytecode Enhancement without Annotation

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping, bytecode

I have the Hibernate Enhanced Bytecodes to work at the Lazy loading at the column level. However, I used @Entity for the DTOs for the bytecode enhancement to work. However, we want to move away using any Annotations on our DTOs - is there a way to work this using only Hibernate Mapping files? I tried without Annotation and it did not enhance...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Hibernate enhancer determines if a class should be enhanced by delegating to an `EnhancementContext` implementation. The [`DefaultEnhancementContext`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/ba3359fe62be258638554fe23a2a0a6a50f7e732/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/bytecode/enhance/spi/DefaultEnhancementContext.java) enhances only by checking for the `Entity` annotation. The [creation of this enhancement context is currently hard-coded into the Maven plugin implementation](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/159bc99a36d86988b61b88ba91eec82cac044e1c/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/tool/enhance/EnhancementTask.java). You would need to achieve what you are asking for.